# How do I calculate the fitted values of an Arma model

Tags: arma

I am studying the ARMA models, and I am breaking my head on something probably straightforward but that I can't see.

I generated in R a simple AR(1) model, and used the function ARIMA to estimate its coefficients. I get two coefficients, an AR(1) coefficient and an intercept.

Now I am trying to calculate myself the fitted values. On another post on StackExchange I found that I can find the fitted value Y(i) by doing

`Y(i-1)*model$coef[1] + ((1-model$coef[1])*model$coef[2])`

Can somebody please explain why one has to multiply the intercept with 1 minus the AR(1) coefficient?

Thanks in advance!

Kasper

PS This is the other question I was reffering to: [Computing the fitted value for the first observation in a time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32575/computing-the-fitted-value-for-the-first-observation-in-a-time-series)

Comment: I am glad I found my answer: Issue 1 on this website explains my questions: http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm